# Is there a terminal command to list everything my system knows about a file?

Tags: terminal, metadata

i.e Is there a way to print all attributes with "attr" and "xattr" ? I want to see all the information (metadata?) that is available to me about a file. For example, can I see the "users" (MAC addresses?) who created and/or have subsequently touched the file? Can I see the date it was created and subsequently modified?

By "metadata" I think I mean all the information my system knows about the file, except for the contents of the file itself. i.e. date created, date modified, original author, all modifying authors (inc. last touch) if the system keeps that information, version history if it's available etc. The file I am working with is adobe acrobat but I also want to know for other types of files. I am using OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: Different types of files have different types of metadata. The answer for one type of file is unlikely to be the same for any other type of file.

Comment: I do not think you can get anything other than what ``mdls your.file`` and ``ls -l your.file`` show. Also, Terminal has nothing to do with your question, it is just a GUI. The word you're looking for is "console", or at least "bash".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is the raw option of the mdls command.

```
mdls -raw ~/pictures/photo1.jpg
```